# Is there any way to stylize articles one by one?

Tags: posts, css

I'm new in wordpress thing and im trying to edit my posts. my problem is:

I'm editing posts in `index.php`

---------index.php----------

```
<?php get_header();?>
```

```
<div id="post-style">

    <h1 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

</div>



<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<h1 class="title">Ups...</h1>

<p>... pedimos desculpa mas nenhum <em>post</em> foi encontrado!</p>

<?php endif; ?>

<p align="center"><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p>
```

---------end----------

I have 3 posts inline and they all have the same style except the middle one which I would like to be a little different.

Comment: please post the full code of the loop of index.php.

Answer (score 2):

The `$current_post` property of the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object for the Loop should tell you which post you are on. Something like this should work:

```
<?php $pclass = ($wp_query->current_post === 1)  ? 'middle-post-class' : 'first-last-class' ; ?>
<div id="post-style" <?php post_class($pclass); ?> >

    <h1 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

</div>
```

The built in Loop counter-- `$current_post`-- starts from 0. That is why the second post is 1, and not 2.

Caveats: Your theme may already be using [`post_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) somewhere else. You  may not want to use it a second time. And if this is a custom `WP_Query` Loop the name of the object may be different-- that is, `$my_query` instead of `wp_query`, for example.

Comment: +1. `post_class()` is the right answer.

Comment: @Andrew28 if this solved the problem mark it as the accepted answer please.